# How to show curl output in html format in php

Tags: php, curl

I set code to hit the links to the proxy list in php. The hit is generated succesfully. and I am getting the output in html. but this html is not in display proper on browswer. I want exact  html in return from the proxy. any body know how to do it please give me some idea about it here is the code which I am using

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
$timeout = 30;
$proxies = file("proxy.txt");
$r="https://www.abcdefgth.com";
// Not more than 2 at a time
for($x=0;$x<2000; $x++){
//setting time limit to zero will ensure the script doesn't get timed out
set_time_limit(30);

//now we will separate proxy address from the port
//$PROXY_URL=$proxies[$getrand[$x]];
echo $proxies[$x];
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$r);
curl_setopt($curl , CURLOPT_PROXY ,  preg_replace('/\s+/', '',$proxies[$x]));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.0.5) Gecko/2008120122 Firefox/3.0.5");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://google.com/");
$text = curl_exec($curl);

echo "Hit Generated:";


}

?>
```

Comment: We don't know what format is __proper__. So, __no__, noone has no idea.

Comment: right after <?php , add `header("content-type: text/plain;charset=utf8");` - does it display correctly then?

Answer (score 1):

A simple look into the documentation of the function you use would have answered your question:

On http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php it clearly states right in the "Return value" section that you receive back either a *boolean* value from that function. *Except* if you have specified the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` flag which you did *not* do you in code.

So have a try adding

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

Followed by *any* attempt to actually *output* the result you receive in `$text`, which you also forgot.

Comment: its all mess up I want nice html here in return

Comment: @azadchouhan Looks like "nice html" to me. I assume you refer to missing style rules. But those are not part of the html, you have to add them.